# How can we prove the limit case in Kummer`s test.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The book said by the given proof you can prove the limit case easily but I do not know how, could anyone explain this for me please.

Here is the test and the proof of cases not including limit case:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim \mathcal{K}_n = \mathcal{K}$ exists, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathcal{K} - \epsilon < \mathcal{K_n} < \mathcal {K} + \epsilon$ when $n \geqslant N$.

If $\mathcal{K} > 0$, taking $\epsilon = \mathcal{K}/2= r$ we have $\mathcal{K}_n > r > 0$ for all $n \geqslant N$ which corresponds to the first case where Kummer's test implies convergence.

Similarly, if $\mathcal{K} < 0$, taking $\epsilon = -\mathcal{K}/2$ we have $\mathcal{K}_n < \mathcal{K}/2 < 0$ for all $n \geqslant N$ which corresponds to  the second case where Kummer's test implies divergence.

Comment: why the first line is true? which criteria did you use?

Comment: @Idonotknow: That is the definition of the limit -- equivalent to $|\mathcal{K}_n - \mathcal{K}| < \epsilon$ when $n \geqslant N$.

Comment: I think in the second case $\epsilon = r $ not $ -r $ ..... am I correct?

Comment: In any case $\mathcal{K}_n < \mathcal{K} + \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$.  When $\mathcal{K} < 0$, I choose $\epsilon = -\mathcal{K}/2$ since it must be a positive number.  Thus $\mathcal {K_n} < \mathcal{K} - \mathcal{K}/2 = \mathcal{K}/2 < 0$.  You are correct about $-r$ and we really don't need to mention it as the second case is about $\mathcal{K} < 0$.

Comment: @Idonotknow: Thank you for reading this carefully.